# Como chamar um método de um fragment em uma activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

eu preciso usar um método de uma fragment dentro de uma activity, mas eu não consigo passar uma referencia para essa activity. Alguem pode me ajudar?

A ideia é essa:

```
    public class MinhaFragment extends Fragment{
    ...

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         if (view.getId() == R.id.fab) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(),MinhaActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
      }

      public void showMessage(String message) {
         Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(this.getView(), message, 
         Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
         snackbar.show();
      }
   }
```

Essa é a minha activity

```
public class MinhaActivity extends Activity{
   ...

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     //chamar o metodo do fragment aqui por exemplo
     minhaFragment.showMessage("Teste");
   }

   ...
 }
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O método é esse mesmo ou é um exemplo. A solução dependerá do que ele fizer.

Comment: Nesse caso é só um exemplo, mas o metodo tem que mandar uma string para o fragment que chamou a activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá! :) Não existe uma solução ideal para esse tipo de problema, no máximo se pode identificar nomes, por exemplo, você pode descobrir o nome da activity que chamou outra activity atráves do método `getCallingActivity`.

Uma solução **não recomendada** seria usar um método estático na activity e passar o fragment para uma variável estática.

Mas muito provavelmente você está querendo fazer algo que existe um jeito melhor de fazer, se você deseja passar informações para o fragment que chamou a activity e identificar o momento que activity é encerrada, você deve chamar essa activity com o método `startActivityForResult` e na activity antes de encerrar ela você deve passar as informações por `intent` com o método `setResult`

**Exemplo:**

No fragment:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MinhaActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Na activity que foi chamada (MinhaActivity):

```
Intent retornoIntent = new Intent();
retornoIntent.putExtra("resultadoid",resultado);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,retornoIntent);
finish();
```

E no fragment que chamou MinhaActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String resultado = data.getStringExtra("resultadoid");
            //Momento exato quando a activity chamada por esse fragment é 
            //encerrada e o estado do app volta para esse fragment
        }
    }
}
```

Ou seja, como não existe um bom motivo para chamar um método de um fragment que não está sendo usado (pois o estado atual do app está numa Activity depois do Fragment), não devemos chamar um método de algum lugar do app que não pertence ao estado atual, ao invés, devemos identificar o momento exato que voltamos para o estado anterior e quando necessário utilizar as informações necessárias do estado que acabou de ser encerrado

**Observação**

É muito importante mostrar aqui que o Fragment não irá ter chegado no método `onActivityResult` sem que a Activity que possua esse Fragment chame `onActivityResult` deste Fragment. Exemplo supondo que o FragmentA está dentro da ActivityA:

Exemplo - ActivityA:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    fragmentA.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data); 
    //É necessário fazer isso para que o fragmentA tenha seu método onActivityResult chamado
}
```

Abraços :)

Comment: Obrigado DigaoParceiro pela ajuda e pela explicação. Eu achei uma outra solução, mas eu acho que essa funciona melhor. Aqui ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/androidbrasil-dev/LD_D972YbQM ) eu mostro as soluções que tive, você pode olhar e me dizer o que acha?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar essa função numa classe model e chamar instanciando:

```
Classe c = new Classe();
c.mostrarMsg(this, "mensagem")
```

Você também precisa passar o contexto

```
public void mostrarMsg(Context contexto, String mensagem) {
    Toast.makeText(contexto, mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Observação se você for chamar essa função dentro de click de um botão, por exemplo, terá que criar uma variável `Context` fora do escopo:

```
final Context contexto = this;

public void onClick(View view) {
    c.mostrarMsg(contexto, "mensagem");
}
```

e usar dentro do click